# Error starting rails server using Rails Composer

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-2.0, railsapps

I created a new rails application using [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) and it was able to see all the project files.

However, if I start rails server, I'm getting following error -

```
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/rails-bootstrap/config/application.rb:7:in `<top    (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-bootstrap/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-bootstrap/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-bootstrap/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am unsure of what I'm missing here. I tried searching for solution by looking for the error, but with no success.

Comment: The rails-bootstrap application is intended for Rails 4.1. It looks like you are running it under rails 4.0.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade by rails for this application and not for remaining projects as 4.0 is the stable version?

Comment: Use RVM to switch gemsets. Make a gemset for Rails 4.1 and another for Rails 4.0.

Comment: @DanielKehoe I updated my Rails to 4.1 but again if I run my app, I'm getting following error - 
`def exec_runtime(filename)
        output = sh("#{shell_escape(*(binary.split(' ') << filename))} 2>&1")
        if $?.success?
          output
        else
          raise RuntimeError, output
        end
      end`

Comment: This is from file - exec_runtimeexecjs (2.0.2) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb

Comment: You're on Ubuntu? Have you followed the complete install instructions here: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html and installed node.js or therubyracer? Can you build and run a simple Rails app with ```rails new```?

Comment: @DanielKehoe I could run my other rails app. I am on Mac OSX Maverick.

Comment: You're using Rails 4.1 and you've built a new app with ```rails new```? And it runs? If so, try cloning the app from the GitHub repo and see if it runs: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap

Comment: @DanielKehoe I cloned your project and was unable to start rails server as it is asking me to install ruby 2.1.1
Downloaded your project too and that's the difference in the Gemfile too.

Comment: Yes, you need Ruby 2.1.1. The README files for both Rails Composer and the rails-bootstrap application both indicate Ruby 2.1.1 is a requirement.